# Error a la hora de hacer listas desplegables en Excel,

Tags: excel

Antes del 2022, en Excel se podían hacer listas desplegables a partir de tablas una vez que se le daba formato a la lista de tabla y se le colocaba nombre. Con  este proceso se seguía el procedimiento:

Validación de datos > Permitir Lista > Origen y allí se indicaba = nombre_de_la_tabla.

Ahora, al hacer este mismo procedimiento indica el siguiente mensaje de aviso:

[image: IMANGEN DEL ERROR INDICADO, EN ORIGEN SE INDICA EL NOMBRE DE LA TABLA]

Es decir no comprende que es una tabla y obviamente llama a la tabla con el igual

¡Alguna persona podría ayudarme lo agradezco!

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su preocupación. Detallo la situación:  En excel se realiza la validación por medio de listas, a partir de un "array", a veces esos array son dinámicos y requieren incorporar nueva información, por ejemplo un producto nuevo. Antes Excel permitía implementar tablas de una columna como listas. En el menú (descrito arriba) bastaba con usar = nombre de tabla (UNIV2), automáticamente Excel entendía que el valor era la tabla. Con la nueva actualización esto no ocurre así y muestra el error indicado, ya, por suerte Alfabravo mandó la solución al problema. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con `=INDIRECT("UNIV2")`

o crea `UNIV2` como un *named range* (no recuerdo el nombre en español) desde el menú Fórmulas, creando un nombre (`rangeUniv2`) y que refiera a `=UNIV2`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y usa ese nombre de Named Range como valor en tu validación (en vez de `=UNIV2` sería `=rangeUniv2`)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la solución, en efecto al aplicar la función = INDIRECT("Nombre de la tabla") hace la lista con la información de toda la tabla, esta solución es sumamente valiosa pues las listas que yo elaboro son dinámicas y cambian cada 6 meses. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: @Gerard Súper!!! Me alegra que sirviera. Puedes marcar como aceptada la respuesta con el tick que está a la izquierda de la respuesta, bajo los votos :)

Comment: Listo muchas gracias